# java Workbook' is abstract; cannot be instantiated

Tags: java, excel, csv, spreadsheet, hssfworkbook

I was using `org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook` im my export implementation and after SonarQube warns "*Use 'org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook' here; it is a more general type than 'XSSFWorkbook'.*", I switched to `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook`.

However, as Workbook is an abstract class, IntelliJ gives "*'Workbook' is abstract; cannot be instantiated*" error. So, how should I fix the problem in the following class?

```
public class WorkSheet {

    private Workbook workbook;
    private Sheet sheet;
    private AtomicInteger rowCount;

    public WorkSheet(String title) {
        this.workbook = new Workbook(); // <-- here is the problem
        this.sheet = workbook.createSheet(title);
        this.rowCount = new AtomicInteger(0);
    }

    public Workbook getWorkbook() {
        return workbook;
    }

    public Sheet getSheet() {
        return sheet;
    }

    public AtomicInteger getRowCount() {
        return rowCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `Workbook` as your variable type but create an instance of `XSSFWorkbook`.

Comment: seems to be an interface https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html

Comment: @khelwood Thanks a lot for help. Do you mean that it is something like `List<String> myList = new Arraylist()`, "programming to interface" issue ?

Comment: @Jonathan Yes, that is what it is.

Comment: @khelwood Another issue is that, when I use `this.workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();`, I will use both libraries: `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook` and `org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook`. Is that ok?

Comment: @Jonathan That sounds right.

Answer (score 0):

> *“java Workbook' is abstract; cannot be instantiated”*

Use Workbook as your variable type but create an instance of `XSSFWorkbook`:

instead of: 
`Workbook workbook = new Workbook();`

use this:

`this.workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();`